# python unzip all files to parent directory

Tags: python, unzip, zip

How can I extract all the .zip files in a certain directory to its parent directory?
I tried:

```
import zipfile
parent_directory = '../input'
directory = '../input/zip'
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(directory,f), "r") as z:
        z.extractall(parent_directory)
```

However the unzipped files are not saved in '..input/zip', they are saved in nested folders

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit exaggerated.
After files are unzipped, I run this to:

1. move the original .zip file up one directory level. (to avoid /src_filename' already exists error)
2. move all files from all subdirectories into the zip parent directory.
3. move the original .zip file back into the parent directory.

```py
import os
import shutil

src = r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PythonZip\PyUnzip01\child_dir\unzip_test2'
dest = r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PythonZip\PyUnzip01\child_dir'
pdir = '../PyUnzip01'

os.replace(r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PythonZip\PyUnzip01\child_dir\unzip_test2.zip", r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PythonZip\PyUnzip01\unzip_test2.zip")

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        shutil.move(path, dest)

os.replace(r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PythonZip\PyUnzip01\unzip_test2.zip", r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\PythonZip\PyUnzip01\child_dir\unzip_test2.zip")
```

Comment: how do you unzip all the files? The problem I get is that I'm not sure how to specify the location to be saved at. I need to use relative path because I run the script from docker and if I simply write z.extractall(parent_directory) then it won't save it where I want. e.g. instead of '../dir/' is is saved in '/dir/zip/dir'